# how to search keyword in different website using google searching

Tags: c#, browser, web

i want to search keyword in Google. i have tried the following code to enter keyword and click the search button through a c# program.

```
    private void WebForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser1.Height = 1000;
            webBrowser1.Width = 1000;
            this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com.au");
       }
```

my documentcompleted method is:

```
    public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
        textElement.SetAttribute("value", "mlm company");
        HtmlElement btnElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0];
        btnElement.InvokeMember("click");

    }
```

now i can go through different links of the Google search page.....
i want to get email, title and url of the websites that are searched and retrieved by the Google through my code. i can also get url of every website. now the problem is, how to search email, title in every website because every website have different structure....

i have tried the following code but was unsuccessful.

```
HtmlNode mytd3 = mydocument4.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//html/body/article/section/section[2]/section[2]/ul/li[1]");
HtmlNode mytd4 = mydocument4.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//html/body/article/section/section[2]/div/p[2]");
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you instead create a [Google Alert](http://www.google.com/alerts) and then create a recipe in [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) to write the results of the Google search to a file in your [Dropbox](http://Dropbox.com)?  Then you can easily parse the contents of the text file in your Dropbox folder.

Here is a sample IFTTT recipe that might be exactly what you need: https://ifttt.com/recipes/66982